# using max-n-of to control the number of arcs that link nodes?

Tags: netlogo

Hi please could somebody write a snippet of sample code to show how I would use max-n-of nodes to control the number of incident nodes that a node has in a network? Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am new.

Answer (score 1):

That's not what `max-n-of` does. Rather, it gives you a list of turtles (or in your case, nodes) that has the highest number of whatever reporter block you pass as parameter. The documentation for `max-n-of` is [here](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#max-n-of).

If you want limit the number of nodes that are connected to other nodes, you will probably want to use `count my-links` and then not create links between nodes that have more than whatever maximum number of connected nodes you want. So ask your nodes to do something like:

```
to connect-nodes ;; turtle/node procedure
let potential-connections other turtles with [count my-links < the-max-connections]
if count my-links < the-max-connections and any? potential-connections [
  create-link-with one-of potential-connections
]
end
```